# Align ul to bottom in fixed div

Tags: css, html, position, alignment

I created two ul's in a fixed sidebar. 
I tried to align to blue ul to the bottom of the fixed div, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="sidebar">
<ul style="background:green;">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
<ul class="align-bottom" style="background:blue;">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
MAIN CONTENT
</div>

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: grey;
  width: 150px;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.align-bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fj0b6jx3/6/#&togetherjs=2v1pIMRuTT

Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.align-bottom` position from `relative` to `absolute`

```
.align-bottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:150px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qnbyxyay/1/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** *just realised that your original solution didn't include `position: absolute;` ... still - if what i did say, helped too* - welcome :D

ul's have margins applied to them, so all you should need to do is...

```
  .align-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:150px;
    margin: 0; // add this
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question**
You seem to be looking to position a child element at the bottom of the parent element

**Answer**
Set the child css to have a position Absolute

My answer explained:
Making an element have a relative position, means your moving the element from its default initial position (before styling was applied).

You therefore said, can you move to the bottom of your self, (it cant)

By specifying absolute
You are using the parent element, and therefore you can move to the bottom of a parent element